# Check if there's an empty place arround a button

Tags: java, swing, graphics, 2d, windowbuilder

I am making an sliding puzzle game as my college project. The game concept is: you have a 3x3 table but with 8 buttons. When you click a button it have to move itself to an empty place. Is there any way to check if there's an empty place arround my button?

Comment: If you do not post some code it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: That depends on how you modeled your actual *game*. Whether there is "empty space" should **not** be decided by the GUI in any way. It should be represented in the *model*. You should always know where a tile can move, even if the GUI is not shown on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

you can put a boolean field in your button class and check it when user requests to move
if you want I can write the exact code.
Good Luck!